# How to debug conda SAT solver pruning Python options to zero?

Tags: python, dependencies, anaconda, conda, sat

I'm observing a `conda install ...` failure in which the `conda` SAT solver is pruning my options for `python` to zero:

```
{snip}
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(400): scipy: pruned from 391 -> 127
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(400): python: pruned from 70 -> 0
DEBUG conda.common.logic:get_sat_solver_cls(281): Using SAT solver interface 'pycosat'.
DEBUG conda.resolve:gen_clauses(688): gen_clauses returning with clause count: 81241
{snip}
```

And I'm wondering:

**How does one debug this?**

That is, how do I get the `conda` SAT solver to give me some clues as to which packages' `python` specifications are conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conda install` accepts the option `-v` up to three times, giving you more output with each. Your output shows DEBUG level, so you can go one higher to TRACE level.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Output,%20Prompt,%20and%20Flow%20Control%20Options